# How to extend middleware to custom classes outside the MVC scope (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, middleware

I am connecting to Shopify's API with the gem `omniauth-shopify-oauth2`.

In `config/initializers/shopify.rb` I am setting my `OmniAuth::Builder` like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shopify, "my_shopify_api_key", "my_shopify_secret",
    scope: 'read_orders',
    setup: lambda { |env| params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
                        env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = "http://#{params['shop']}" }
end
```

Then from any controller file I can access Shopify's API like this:

```
omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
if omniauth && omniauth[:provider] && omniauth[:provider] == "shopify"
  token     = omniauth['credentials'].token
  session   = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("#{username}.myshopify.com", token)
  ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
  # Do stuff with the session
  ShopifyAPI::Base.clear_session
end
```

If, on the other hand, I move the controller functionality to e.g. `app/my_custom_folder/my_custom_file.rb` I get an error in the very first line of code:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `request' for #<MyCustomClass:0x007fe07ec11f68>):
```

I assume that the error is raised because my custom classes and files can't access the middleware functionality. So how can I extend the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails auto-requires everything in certain directories, but `my_custom_folder` isn't one of those.

You could add something like this to `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/my_custom_folder
)
```

Or, you could drop `my_custom_file.rb` in a blessed location like `app/controllers/concerns`

**ALSO:**

It seems to me that the code you moved to `my_custom_file.rb` probably also expects to be inside a controller, which has access to `request` (through `ActionController::Base`).

Without knowing what `my_custom_file.rb` looks like, I would propose you set it up as an include like so:

```
# in app/controllers/concerns/my_custom_file.rb
module MyCustomFile
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # if necessary to run stuff on include:
    # before_action :do_some_oauth_shopify_stuff
  end

  # This will be treated as part of all controllers now:
  def do_some_oauth_shopify_stuff
    # your code
  end
end

# near top of app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MyCustomFile
  # rest of application_controller.rb
end
```

And maybe pick a better name for the module/file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the same error is raised.

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen Updated my answer under ALSO: Hope it helps!